# Change default junction tablename in entity framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with entity framework and I have a many to many relationship using junction tables.

As I understand it should be generated so my context looks like this:

```
public DbSet<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
public DbSet<SkillSet> SkillSets { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Candidate>().HasMany(t => t.SkillSets).WithMany(t => t.Candidates)
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("candidate_skillset");
            m.MapLeftKey("candidate_id");
            m.MapRightKey("skillset_id");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SkillSet>().ToTable("skillset");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Candidate>().ToTable("candidate");
    }
```

Candidate model:

```
namespace CandidateCatalog.Model
{
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("candidate")]
public class Candidate
{ 
    #region Simple propertied

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Column("firstname")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region reference properties

    public int? commendation_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("commendation_id")]
    public Commendation commendation { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SkillSet> SkillSets { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Skillset model:

```
namespace CandidateCatalog.Model
{
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("skillset")]
public class SkillSet : SimpleDictionary
{
    public virtual ICollection<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
}
}
```

Entity Framework generated some default junction table name, so as I presume I need to define that name. And here is the problem, how this can be done?

EDIT:

I Have added fluent api;

It can see property:

```
 public ICollection<SkillSet> SkillSets { get; set; }
```

But when I try for example:

```
   var ca = this._catalog.Candidates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 125).SkillSets;
```

I am getting 0 as if collection is never filled, Ive double check DB relations are there.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149110/how-to-represent-bridge-table-in-entity-framework-code-first). I think It is going to help you, I think It is the same case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use  FluentAPI like:

Models:

```
public class Candidate
{
    [Key]
    public int CandidateId { get; set; }

    Column("firstname")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<SkillSet> SkillSets { get; set; }
}



public class SkillSet : SimpleDictionary
{
    [Key]
    public int SkillSetId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
}
```

FluentAPI

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<SkillSet>()
                .HasMany<Candidate>(s => s.Candidates)
                .WithMany(c => c.SkillSets)
                .Map(cs =>
                {
                    cs.MapLeftKey("SkillSetId");
                    cs.MapRightKey("CandidateId");
                    cs.ToTable("candidate_skillset");
                });
    modelBuilder.Entity<SkillSet>().ToTable("skillset");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Candidate>().ToTable("candidate");
}
```

Comment: The correct answer is "you need to use Fluent API like this ..." and show the `HasMany` / `WithMany` / `Map` chain with `ToTable` being the essential part addressing the OP question. The first part with explicit link table is incorrect because it requires changing the navigation properties to be of type `ICollection<CandidateSkillset>`