# How to bridge a table on itself using EF Core Code-First

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

This is a operation i have done many times in the past using database-first approach. I'm now trying it with code-first using EF Core and i'm failing horribly.

I have the following model:

```
public class DataMapping
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; } 
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public bool IgnoreProperty { get; set; } 

    [NotMapped] //<-- I had to add this as the migration was complaining that it did not know what the relation was
    public List<DataMappingRelation> DataMappingRelations { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
}
```

and a Bridge model that basically creates a relations between two DataMapping items in the same table:

```
public class DataMappingRelation
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DataMappingId")]
    public long? DataMapping1Id { get; set; }
    public DataMapping DataMapping1 { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("DataMappingId")]
    public long? DataMapping2Id { get; set; }
    public DataMapping DataMapping2 { get; set; }
}
```

However this call does not work:

```
return _context.DataMappings.Where(x => x.Model == type.FullName)
            .Include(x=>x.DataMappingRelations)
            .ToList();
```

It does not like the Include and throws a null ref exception.

All i basically need to do here is for a given "DataMapping" get all the related DataMapping items based on the relations in the "DataMappingRelations" table.

Yes i have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149110/how-to-represent-bridge-table-in-entity-framework-code-first) but again, it is an example of two seperate tables, not a single table bridging on itself.

I suspect i have done all of this wrong. How can i get this to work? All the examples i have found are bridging two seperate tables. this would be bridging the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `many-to-many` with self but your whole configuration looks messy.

So first, your `DataMapping` model class should contain two list navigation properties for two foreign keys in the `DataMappingRelation` as follows:

```
public class DataMapping
{
    ......

    public List<DataMappingRelation> DataMapping1Relations { get; set; }

    public List<DataMappingRelation> DataMapping2Relations { get; set; }

    .........
}
```

Now remove `[ForeignKey("DataMappingId")]` attribute from both `DataMapping1` and `DataMapping2` foreign keys as follows:

```
public class DataMappingRelation
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long? DataMapping1Id { get; set; }
    public DataMapping DataMapping1 { get; set; } 

    public long? DataMapping2Id { get; set; }
    public DataMapping DataMapping2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then the `Fluent API` configuration should be as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<DataMappingRelation>()
         .HasOne(dmr => dmr.DataMapping1)
         .WithMany(dm => dm.DataMapping1Relations)
         .HasForeignKey(dmr => dmr.DataMapping1Id)
         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

     modelBuilder.Entity<DataMappingRelation>()
         .HasOne(dmr => dmr.DataMapping2)
         .WithMany(dm => dm.DataMapping2Relations)
         .HasForeignKey(dmr => dmr.DataMapping2Id)
         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```